# I'm getting bounce when I send an email to a specific address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm getting bounce when I send an email to a specific address using SES, from gmail the mail is delivered correctly

For Transient -> General AWS says `The recipient's email provider sent a general bounce message. You might be able to send a message to the same recipient in the future if the issue that caused the message to bounce is resolved.`
How can I fix the issue if I do not know the problem?

```
"eventType":"Bounce",
"bounce":{
"bounceType":"Transient",
"bounceSubType":"General",
"bouncedRecipients":[
{
"emailAddress":"{some_email}",
"action":"failed",
"status":"5.7.8",
"diagnosticCode":"smtp; 535 5.7.8 Error: blocked by Block Address check from 54.240.8.90"
}
],
"timestamp":"2019-07-03T19:48:56.445Z",
"feedbackId":"0100016bb962013a-6cd68815-3c51-4216-9946-50f01b923057-000000",
"reportingMTA":"dsn; a8-90.smtp-out.amazonses.com"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much you can do, seems like the recipient side is checking IP reputation and found that SES IP (sending IP)  54.240.8.90 is in the blacklist, it also sent you a bounce back with custom message "smtp; 535 5.7.8 Error: blocked by Block Address check from 54.240.8.90".

Seems like they're using SORBS SPAM .

https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=blacklist%3a54.240.8.90&run=toolpage

http://www.sorbs.net/cgi-bin/db

Couple of things you can try:

1. Remove the IP from SORBS by yourself (it may get added again)
2. Contact AWS to contact them to remove it from Blacklist.
3. Try dedicated IP pool.

Answer (score 0):

@James Dean,

I believe that as per the logs, "54.240.8.90"  is the Email Gateway Server of the recipient that checked the IP reputation and blocked the email. Its good the sender to check his email server IP address in MX toolbox for any blacklisting.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35151908)